# Getting squares instead of text when rendering PDF with ReactDOM.createPortal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I'm developing an application with React where I want to open some components in new windows with the help of createPortal in ReactDOM. Everything is working fine except rendering PDF, which is working great when not rendering it as a child in createPortal.

I have developed my own solution with createPortal but I have also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-new-window with the same result.

PDF libs i have been trying

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-viewer-reactjs

Someone who have experienced the same problem or have a clue of what it might be?

Example

[image: Squares rendered in PDF]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the PDF file it's hard to be certain, but the 'squares' you refer to are a general way of representing the .notdef glyph in a TrueType font. When a font does not contain a specified glyph, then the .notdef glyph is used instead.

The most common reason for this is that the font used by the PDF file is not embedded, which means a substitute must be used. If the substitute font does not have the required glyph then it will be drawn as a .notdef.